# Angular Material mat-list-option

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

Is there a way in Material 2 to detect checkbox is true or false through the event function. Passing $event only detects mouse or keyboard on the typescript side need to detect if it is checked or unchecked.

```
<mat-selection-list #list   >
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let aser of fo; let i = index" (click)="onAreaListControlChanged(aser.ID, aser.Name, aser.Number, $event)"  checkboxPosition="before"    [value]="aser.Number" [selected]="aser.selected"  >
    <span style="font-size:11px"  >{{aser.selected}} {{aser.first}} - {{aser.Number}}</span>
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

typescript

```
onAreaListControlChanged(sid, sname, snum, $event) { if(checked==true else false}
```

Comment: Where did you get the `indeterminateChange` event from? You can only bind a `selectionChange` event to `MatSelectionList`.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to achieve but you can get it from the event's target something like `(click)="onClick($event.toElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-state'))"`

Comment: Just need to get the state of the checkbox when clicked. $event.toElment returns `null
:268 -1
257 null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use MatSelectionList's `selectionChange` event. The event object is a `MatSelectionListChange` which provides the clicked `MatOption` as the `option` property, which in turn gives you the `selected` (checked) value:

```html
<mat-selection-list #list (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event.option)">
  <mat-list-option
    *ngFor="let aser of fo; let i = index"
    (click)="onAreaListControlChanged(aser.ID, aser.Name, aser.Number, $event)"
    checkboxPosition="before"
    [value]="aser.Number"
    [selected]="aser.selected"
  >
    <span style="font-size:11px"
      >{{ aser.selected }} {{ aser.first }} - {{ aser.Number }}</span
    >
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

TS

```js
selectionChange(option: MatListOption) {
  console.log(option.selected);
}
```